# proper way to top align div

Tags: css, html, alignment

I'm using the following to place two pictures next to each other. The pictures are different sizes (the one on the right is taller than on the left) but I want them aligned at the top, not the bottom like they currently are.

Any suggestions on the correct way to top align the second div?

Thanks

```
<div style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px">
<img src="right-side.jpg" alt="taller image">
</div>

<div style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px">
<img src="left-side.jpg" alt="shorter image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way would be to float the container divs like:

```
<div style="display:block; float: left; margin-right: 10px">
    <img src="right-side.jpg" alt="taller image" style="height: 150px;">
</div>

<div style="display:block; float:left; margin-right: 10px">
    <img src="left-side.jpg" alt="shorter image" style="height: 50px;">
</div>​
```

...you actually don't need `display: block;` in that case, because it's the default for that element.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt be using inline-block I would float them both left instead.